# Calling multiple cloud functions inside Google Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am writing a dag to call two functions inside my workflow in Google Composer. I have created a class for it using the SimpleHTTPOperator:

```
class cfSFTP2GCSOp(SimpleHttpOperator):
def execute(self, context):
    http = HttpHook(self.method, http_conn_id=self.http_conn_id)
    self.log.info("Calling HTTP method")
    target_audience = 'https://dw-etl-transactor-unzip-files-nowvpwp6oq-uc.a.run.app'
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    idt = id_token.fetch_id_token(request, target_audience)
    self.headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + idt}
    response = http.run(self.endpoint,
                        self.data,
                        self.headers,
                        self.extra_options)
    self.log.info(response)

    if response == "<Response [200]>":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which I use inside the task to call the function:

```
gcp_cf_dw_etl_transactor_unzip_files = cfSFTP2GCSOp(
    task_id='gcp_cf_dw_etl_unzip_files',
    method='POST',
    http_conn_id='gcp_cf_dw_etl_unzip_files',
    data={},
    endpoint='/',
    headers={},
    response_check=lambda response: True if response == "<Response [200]>" is True else False,
    dag=dag,
)
```

I have to use two tasks to call each of the Cloud Functions I need, but what happens if I need to call multiple Cloud Functions? Is it possible to call all of them inside the same task or I need to continue doing what I am currently doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Composer/Airflow do you use?

Comment: I'm using Cloud Composer 2.0.22 and Airflow 2.2.5